Office.context.mailbox.item.removeHandlerAsync() call fails when called multiple times in quick succession
When Office.context.mailbox.item.removeAttachmentAsync() call is made repetitively in quick succession, the call fails for some files randomly, and the following error shows up on Outlook:

The following attachments couldn't be deleted: <Attachment_Name>. Please try again later.

We have an Outlook add-in that has an attachment handler that gets notified every time an attachment is added. The add-in then attempts to fetch the attachment, and after successfully doing that, it deletes the attachment using Office.context.mailbox.item.removeAttachmentAsync().
If the user uploads ~ 15 files at the same time (by clicking on Attach File, and then selecting around 15 files at the same time, and uploading them), the files get uploaded to Outlook.
For some files, the removal works correctly. But for some files (seemingly at random), the deletion method returns an error.
